# Не работает простой пример

Tags: python

Начал изучать Python, скачал интерпретатор, пишу в файл test.py код

```
x = 0

while x<=10:
    print x
    x += 1
```

Запускаю его, консоль открылась, закрылась. `raw_input()` добавлял, не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить его через IDLE.

Comment: @johniek_comp, не забывайте принимать верные ответы!

Answer (score 1):

Pyton не изучал.
В Linux сделал tst.py и chmod +x tst.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = 0

while x<=10:
    print x
    x += 1

avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$ ./tst.py 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent$
```

Работает.

IMHO если в винде запустить в окошке cmd или powershell, то тоже будет работать. А лучше, [@johniek_comp](/users/5557/johniek_comp), бросьте Вы эту винду.

Comment: Блин, вопрос-то совсем старый. @ReinRaus его зачем-то вытащил.

Comment: Я его не вытаскивал... Просто автор стер текст вопроса, а я откатил обратно, дабы не нарушалась целостность вопроса и ответов.

Comment: На стековерфлове для некроманов есть специальный бэджик ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_input(“Press enter to exit”)
```